# Check-out the Baseline code from Serena Dimension using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, checkout, baseline, serena

I am trying to check-out the baseline code from Dimension into local workspace using Jenkins. I have designed the Jenkins job as parameterized build by passing baseline as input value to the string variable "DM_BASELINE". But I am unaware of how to integrate this string value in the SCM section being defined in the Jenkins job. I have provided project and Dimension repository details in SCM section.

Any help on clarifying this will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by passing the baseline value as the string parameter. The parameter value should be in the format of **product_id:baseline**. In the SCM section of the Jenkins job, pass the project name and folder to monitor as empty or /. Most important point is check the "**Use update**" option in Advanced section.

This will download the baseline code in Dimension to the local workspace via Jenkins.